# How to organize common code in Google App Script project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm newbie of google apps script programming and i would like to organize some common functions across several projects in a separated file, and reference them; I'm expert of C-languege project and in these environment I can make simply a library.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance!
mike

Answer (score 3):

You can consider [writing a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#writingLibrary) with the common function and a library can be easily included in your other projects.

Comment: Thank Amit ! I've seen "Beta" on menù item but recently was removed and now Library functionalities are full supported....and usefull.